# Visual Studio 2008 SP2 Released or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Did Microsoft release SP2 for Visual Studio 2008 ? Or may be any plans in future ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope and since Visual Studio 2010 is coming out, I doubt they ever will...